# org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document for finding element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use this code to click on

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ag-center-cols-container']//div"));

        // check for list elements and print all found elements
        if(!list.isEmpty())
        {
            for (WebElement element : list)
            {
//                System.out.println("Found inner WebElement " + element.getText());
            }
        }

        // iterate sub-elements
        for ( WebElement element : list )
        {
            System.out.println("Searching for " + element.getText());

            if(element.getText().equals(valueToSelect))
            {
                new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='overlay ng-star-inserted']")));

                element.click();
                break;  // We need to put break because the loop will continue and we will get exception
            }
        }
```

But from time to time I get this error at this line `element.getText()`:

```
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Do you know how I can implement a lister in order to fix this issue>

Comment: generally `StaleElementReferenceException` means that the element you trying to access was changed from the moment you got the reference to it. In your specific case I can't know what can we do in order to fix this problem until I will be able to see the site you are working on and the entire Selenium code you are running.

Comment: sounds like the DOM is still populating when you run findElements.  Easiest way to deal with that is include a sleep before calling findElements.  Best way is to functionize the call and try/catch your method calls on the elements in the list.  If you catch StaleElementException, you re-call the function to re-do findElements.  I use:  catch (Exception e)
 {
   if (e.getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException"))
   {  ...re-call function...

Answer (score 2):

> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException:

Indicates that a reference to an element is now "stale" --- the element no longer appears on the DOM of the page. The reason for this expectation is may be your `DOM` got updated or refreshed. For an example, after performing an action like `click()` your `DOM` may get updated or refreshed. In this time when you are trying to find an element on `DOM` you will experience this error.

You have to re-find that element in updated or refreshed `DOM`

> But from time to time I get this error at this line element.getText():

Create a reusable method to handle this exception.

**Code**:

```
public static String getTextFromElement(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
    try {
        return element.getText();
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException e) {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
        return element.getText();
    }
}
```

For example, you can call in this way.

```
System.out.println("Found inner WebElement " + getTextFromElement(element, driver));
```

Comment: If that list was still loading, they'd want to re-get the list of webelement references... best to include the findElements call and the loop in the function and then just re-call the function on catch.  (With sanitycount check to check if it's more than webdriverwait * 2... it's a 1/2 second polling rate.)